Showing a grid view of images and managing them in a terminal?
I looked at handful of TUI file explorers like Ranger and Yazi. but haven't found any that can show a grid of images. I find keyboard navigation of files much more efficient and would like to manage photos in a folder in the terminal, with a grid view like a traditional GUI file explorer.

